# The vite vue3 project cannot be deployed on Github pages (Solved by GitHub Action)

Tags: vuejs3, vite, github-pages

I am a beginner in Vite project. I built a vue project on vite. but I got some trouble when I need to deploy it on github pages.
here is some detail of my code .

package.json

```
{
  "name": "ptwa",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d dist"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-inject": "^5.0.3",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.11.1",
    "jquery": "^3.7.0",
    "vue": "^3.3.11",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.13",
    "vuedraggable": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.5.2",
    "gh-pages": "^6.1.1",
    "vite": "^5.0.8",
    "sass": "^1.62.1"
  }
}
```

And then here is my vite.config.js

```
import {fileURLToPath, URL} from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  base: '/ptwa/',
  plugins: [
    vue(),
  ],
  resolve: {
      alias: {
          '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
      }
  }
})
```

And when I finish building my code I just run:
`npm run deploy`
P.S: I've installed gh-pages in my project

But when I open my pages it display nothing without error info
[image]
you can see my site on
https://rduanchen.github.io/ptwa/

I'm sure that my code run perfectly in dev mode. So, I suppose it isn't syntax error.

Thank you for your patient and hope for your reply.

Comment: [same issue](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/9119).  The root cause is the `_` at the beginning of the filename.  fast solution is to add `.nojekyll` file to your project root.  alternative is to add custom filename sanitize option to vite build config.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply, I didn't have `_ `at the beginning of the filename.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply, I didn't have `_ `at the beginning of the filename. But I still add `.nojekyll` in my project. It display same error message.

Comment: This is your error message: "Failed to load resource **\_plugin-vue_export-helper-x3n3nnut.js:1**".  Therefore, you _do_ you have a `_` at the beginning.  This is not the filename you created, but the filename generated from the build process.  The solutions from my first comment then apply.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried to use GitHub Action, and It deploy on GitHub pages successfully.